# .Net 4.0 Action<in T> not works for me

Tags: .net

here is what I'm trying to do

```
IDictionary<Type, Action<BaseClass>> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<BaseClass>>();

public void Register<T>(Action<T> handler) where T:BaseClass
{
    handlers.Add(typeof(T),handler);
}
```

Its not compiling

Is it possible in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IDictionary<Type, Action<BaseClass>> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<BaseClass>>();

public void Register<T>(Action<T> handler) where T:BaseClass
{
Action<BaseClass> action = x=>handler((T)x);
    handlers.Add(typeof(T),action);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Covariant parameters work in the other direction.

`Action<in T>` allows you to write

```
Action<Animal> baseProcessor = ...;
Action<Cat> catProcessor = baseProcessor;
```

Since all `Cat`s are also `Animals`, this is legal.

---

Had your code been possible, what would happen if I write

```
Action<Cat> catProcessor = ...;
Action<Animal> baseProcessor = catProcessor;
baseProcessor(new Dog());
```

We just passed a `Dog` to a function that takes a `Cat`.